# FastAPI: как задать одинаковый формат выдачи данных для разных функций

Tags: python, python-3.x, fastapi, response

Можно ли средствами FastAPI реализовать следующий функционал:

Есть разные функции:

```
@app.post("/services/overview/")
def services_overview():
    ...
    return output_type1

# запрос на получение полных сведений о проекте
@app.post("/services/get_object/")
def services_object(params: ObjectsParams):
    ...
    return output_type2
```

и т.д.

Требуется чтобы функции на выход выдавали данные в одинаковом формате:

```
{
    code: 1,
    message: '2',
    response: <результат, который выдают функции services_overview, services_object>
}
```

Можно ли это сделать централизованно, а не добавляя код в каждую функцию перед return?

Comment: Ну то есть в какую-то модельку текст ответа оборачивать? Или что конкретно вы подразумеваете под форматом?

Comment: @insolor, именно, например чтобы упаковывать (зиповать) response
если бы еще условно вызов каждой функции был централизованно завернут в try..except, то тогда в случае какого-то падения, можно было бы формировать корректно ошибку и записывать в code, message

Comment: Посмотрите [Handling Error](https://fastapi.tiangolo.com/tutorial/handling-errors/#install-custom-exception-handlers)